# Is there a case that this macro returns value except for false?

Tags: c++

I'm reading this code about Q_ASSERT.
I'm new to C++.

```
#if !defined(Q_ASSERT)
#  if defined(QT_NO_DEBUG) && !defined(QT_FORCE_ASSERTS)
#    define Q_ASSERT(cond) static_cast<void>(false && (cond))
#  else
#    define Q_ASSERT(cond) ((cond) ? static_cast<void>(0) : qt_assert(#cond, __FILE__, __LINE__))
#  endif
#endif
```

`define Q_ASSERT(cond) static_cast<void>(false && (cond))`

Is there a case that this macro returns value except for false?

I think this always returns false...

```
int main() {

    
    cout << "The result of false is" << (false && nullptr) << endl;
}
```

I change the value of right side to various values, but it always returns 0.
This means false, doesn't this?

Comment: Yes. This version of the macro disables assertions. Not only that, it doesn't execute the `cond` at all because of `&&` short-circuiting.

Comment: Yes.  `cond` will never be evaluated at all, due to short-circuiting.   The macro could have quite easily been written as `#define Q_ASSERT(cond) static_cast<void>(false)`.    My guess is that whoever wrote it was fretting about compilers giving warnings about unused arguments  (although, to my knowledge, although several compilers give warnings about named arguments of *functions* that are unused, no compiler/preprocessor gives a similar warning for *macros*).

Comment: @Peter I think your guess is spot-on. But it's not about silencing a warning for an unused *macro* argument. It's to silence warnings about an unused *function* argument at the call site of the macro (for the admittedly very unlikely case of a function that accepts an argument that is only used inside the assertion and nowhere else, i.e. something like `void expect_nonzero(int x) { Q_ASSERT(x != 0); }`).

Comment: *"`false && nullptr`"* -- not a good example, since `nullptr` converts to false. Better would be `false && true`.

Answer (score 1):

From the C++ standard (N3690 5.14-1):

> The && operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually
> converted to bool (Clause 4). The result is true if both operands are true
> and false otherwise. Unlike &, && guarantees left-to-right evaluation: the
> second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is false.

Hence, the result is always `false` since at least one of the operands is `false`. Furthermore, since the first operand is `false`, it is guaranteed by the standard that the second (i.e. `cond`) is not even evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a case that this macro returns value except for false?

No, and that is the point. Assertions are traditionally for debug mode, to catch mistakes during testing. Once testing is done, the assertions are (in theory) no longer helpful. They become wasted effort on the computer's part as it would try to verify a condition that you have already ensured via testing. There is no longer a need to spend time checking the condition, no matter how trivial or expensive that check is.

Probably.

Testing does not always catch every bug, and some people would prefer to keep the cost of checking conditions, even in release mode. Hence the two macros being checked. The first, `QT_NO_DEBUG`, is defined for release mode. When this is defined, assertions should  become no-ops unless the programmer expressed a preference to keep the cost of checking conditions. That is expressed by defining the second macro, `QT_FORCE_ASSERTS`.

So when the macro definition in question is used, the situation is that assertions should become no-ops. This is accomplished by casting a side-effect-free expression to `void`. The compiler will come to the same conclusion you did – the expression always evaluates to false – realize that the statement does nothing, and optimize this instruction out of existence (assuming some level of optimization is enabled, as is traditional for release builds).

Why make it so complex? To keep `cond` in the program after the pre-processor is done. Suppose there is some variable or parameter that is used only in assertions. (Maybe an assertion requires a value cached earlier, such as the size of a container to verify that the container did not grow.) If the conditions for assertions were removed by the pre-processor, the compiler would see that variable/parameter as unused and potentially issue a warning. Keeping the condition until the *compiler* eliminates it avoids that warning.

Another key piece of the puzzle is that `&&` short-circuits. Not only will `false && (cond)` always evaluate to false, but also `cond` is not evaluated. This is relevant in case `cond` has side-effects. Side-effects cannot be optimized out of existence. Short-circuiting avoids any side-effects, which allows the compiler to optimize this statement away.

The end result is that this definition causes assertions to disappear without triggering warnings in the process.

Comment: Another side benefit: `false && (cond)` must at least compile, so it catches typo's in `cond`.

Comment: Compilers might warn (as OP did) that `false && (cond)` is always `false` though... trading one warning by another one.

Comment: @Jarod42 Interesting. I don't recall running into that (and I don't see the OP mentioning compiler warnings). Out of curiosity, which compiler and which warning needs to be turned on?

Comment: I meant OP (not his/her compiler :) ) warns about always `false`. I don't know if some compilers warn about that construct, but I already get warning about conditional always `true` for `if (t >= 0)` in template code when `t` was unsigned...